# Send a variable to jquery function

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to pass a variable to _F.search in this but no luck, can someone please help?

```
(function(window, $) {

 // 'use strict';
//setInterval(function () {alert("Hello")}, 3000);
  var StreamTable = function(container, opts, data) {
    return new _StreamTable(container, opts, data);
  };


  _F.search = function(text){
      alert("search " + text);
    var q = $.trim(text), count = 0;
     // alert(this.last_search_text);
    if (q == this.last_search_text) return;

    this.last_search_text = q;

    if(q.length == 0 ){
      this.render(0);
    }else{
      this.searchInData(q);
      this.render(0);
    }

    this.current_page = 0;
    this.renderPagination(this.pageCount(), this.current_page);
    this.execCallbacks('pagination');
  };
  }
```

I tried

```
onclick ="window.search(5)"
```

from a click button but still did not work.

Answer (score 2):

The search function should be declared like this:

```
window.search = function(text){
```

This will attach the search function to the window object. This will allow you to attach it to the onclick event, like you have in your example:

```
onclick="window.search(5)"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to re-define this code as it is already performing some other function for me.

Comment: _F is declared as  var _F = _StreamTable.prototype;

Comment: Ok, it seems that you are only showing a small portion of the code here. It also seems like you are using a component I am unfamiliar with - i.e streamtable

Comment: Yes I only showed a small part because it is fairly long. It is from the Stream_table.js code.

Comment: It's from the library code itself? In that case `_StreamTable.search(text)` should just work... right?

Comment: Usually you table would have a name and you would call search on that, but I am not familiar with that library.